# I need to automate Excel solver by using Macro . I have a problem in making "set objective value" a reference cell not a hard code

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am using the solver to build efficient portfolio of stocks. I must automate the solver in full.

My problem is how to input in solver window slot "**set objective value of** " to be ***a reference cell and NOT a hard code value***. Of course the reference cell shall have different values whenever we change the input / stocks selection.

Therefore , It is a crucial step to make this "objective value of " to be a reference cell in order  to fully automate my solver module.

I am average user . Pls advise me what are the VBA sentences I should add and change in the Macro VBA to make my Macro run automatically & smoothly .

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
' Automate Solver
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+K
'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
    Range("A1").Select
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$39", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Y$14:$Y$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$Y$34", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$Y$14:$Y$33", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$39", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Y$14:$Y$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$39", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Y$14:$Y$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$39", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Y$14:$Y$33", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, **ValueOf:=0.154**, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, **ValueOf:=0.154**, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.154, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, **ValueOf:=0.172**, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, **ValueOf:=0.172**, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$38", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0.172, ByChange:= _
        "$Y$14:$Y$33", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
End Sub
```

The above bold values 0.154 & 0.172 needs to be replaced with cell reference and NOT a hard code. for example i need to replace 0.154 to be " **ValueOf:=target1** and 0.172 to be "**ValueOf:=target2**" ....etc . pls advise.

Comment: So is the `reference cell` a fixed cell? Or you need the code to allow you select one?

Comment: It is a fixed cell . but mind you in my model I have 8 targets , so I have or I need to create 8 reference cells. All reference cells are in fixed place/position that will not change.

Comment: SolverMax have provided an answer which i believe you can adopt to your need. If you have multiple reference cells and thus need to do multiple instance of solver, just repeat the code and change the cell assignment to `TargetValue` each time. @sherif

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable, give it a value, and then use it where you're currently using a hard-coded value. That is:

```
Dim TargetValue As Double
```

...

```
TargetValue = 0.514
SolverOk SetCell:="$D$39", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=TargetValue, ByChange:="$Y$14:$Y$33", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

Or you can get the value from a cell, e.g. A1:

```
TargetValue = Range("A1").Value
```

Also, you can remove the many duplicate lines of code, to make things simpler.

Comment: Hello, the hard code 0.154 , is just a figure I create in solver for only one time/1st time [arbitrary figure] to satisfy SOLVER a must parameter (value of) and to create the Macro VBA. Then I go to MACRO VBA to change/edit the figure to reference cell . So why in your answer you specified "targetvalue" =0.154

Comment: @sherif Then use the alternative I suggested of using a cell. If that doesn't work, then explain exactly what you're trying to do.